# Unity WebPlayer "Failed to initialize player's 3D settings"?

Tags: web, unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, unity-web-player

I am trying to execute one of [Daqri's](http://daqri.com/) AR [demos](http://developer.daqri.com/daqri-experience-toolkit/sample-experiences), but I keep getting

> "Failed to initialize player's 3D settings"

...error every time I try to run the demo (Which is essentially a webpage).

I am using unity 5.0.0f4 and even 4.5.3f3 (As a tried to implement a fix that I found on a forum...it didn't work). I am on Windows 8.1.

- I'm fresh out of ideas can anyone run the examples in the demos?
- What do I do to fix my WebPlayer so that it can run the demos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/908378/web-player-fails-with-failed-to-initialize-players.html). Furthermore, I would just uninstall everything and just reinstall with a stable version of Unity 5.